# Working in Selenium with elements on the page after the popup has been closed

Tags: java, selenium

I want to switch the language on [habr.com](https://habr.com/) at the bottom of the page and then check if the language has changed. A popup window will appear to change the language. But after closing it, I cannot interact with elements on the page. What should I do to make the items available?
Here is my code.

```
    @FindBy(css = "a.js-show_lang_settings")
    public WebElement languageSettingsLink;

    @FindBy(css = "[for='hl_langs_en']")
    public WebElement interfaceEnglishLabel;

    @FindBy(css = "[for='fl_langs_en']")
    public WebElement publicationEnglishLabel;

    @FindBy(css = "[for='fl_langs_ru']")
    public WebElement publicationRussianLabel;

    @FindBy(css = ".form__footer_lang-settings > button")
    public WebElement saveLanguageSettingsButton;

    @FindBy(className = "tabs-menu__item-text_active")
    public WebElement firstTabHeader;

    public void openLanguageSettingMenu(){
        languageSettingsLink.click();
    }

    public void changeLanguage(){
        interfaceEnglishLabel.click();
        publicationRussianLabel.click();
        publicationEnglishLabel.click();
        saveLanguageSettingsButton.click();
    }
```

And then I want to interact with the element on the page.

```
    assertEquals(mainPage.firstTabHeader.getText(), "Articles");
```

But I get

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :
Actual   :Articles
```

Comment: I didn't get that popup and the website language is English

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implicitlyWait` to wait for the page to refresh.

You can try this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```